# Debug Async MVC Action Controller with nested Async Methods

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asynchronous, async-await

I am calling a ASYNC method in an MVC4 application.  This method has to call a dozen or so other methods, which are nested.   My issue is that if any of these nested methods break, it passes the error to the parent method.  Since they are all nested, it just keeps passing up the chain returning to the HTTP context the generic error message.

Since I have so many nested methods, I have no clue how to find more information on the error.  Even a simple line that broke would be extremely helpful.

Right now I am resorting to breaking every line to see which ran last before it stop responding.  This Method alone, with it's nested methods, are over 2000 lines of code.  As you can tell, this is a very un-effective way at debugging.

Any help at a better way of finding out where a ASYNC method actually broke, when in nested methods, would be extremely helpful.  I really want to avoid doing a Try/Catch on every method I have.

-- Edit --

This has been answered. I put my solution below and will mark it as answered in two days, per StackOverflow restrictions.

Comment: Why can't you just run it under debugger? It should break automatically on uncaught exceptions, I think.

Comment: In a normal method it does. In a ASYNC method (even if you were to use a backgroundWorker) it does not break at the line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently if I put a Try/Catch on the first call inside my Action Method it at least gives me the line in the stack trace.  Once noting this, I added ELMAH and inspected my error log when throwing a generic exception.  It appears that the line gets passed back to ELMAH also.

While this is not nearly as nice as normal exception breaking in visual studio, it allows me to easily put a breakpoint on that exact line to see what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, asynchronous "stack traces" do not work very well out of the box.

You can do your own tracing [using a technique I describe in this blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/implicit-async-context-asynclocal.html). Or you could try installing my [`async` diagnostics package](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/05/announcement-async-diagnostics.html) which adds the asynchronous "stack trace" to the exception's `Data` property (note: not logged by default in ELMAH). However, this package is not yet production-ready, so I recommend uninstalling before deploying.